# How to combine SQL queries for same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched but not found any examples for my particular problem.

I am trying to strip some unwanted text from a column containing department names.  I am trying to combine 2 queries to do this.

This first query strips all characters after the colon in the name:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', DB.Table.DEPT)>0 
THEN
LEFT(DB.Table.DEPT, CHARINDEX(':', DB.Table.DEPT)-1) 
ELSE 
DB.Table.DEPT
END
FROM
DB.Table
```

The second query strips the prefix from the name:

```
SELECT
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE (DB.Table.DEPT,'[NA1] ','') 
,'[NA2] ', '')
,'[NA3] ', '')
FROM
DB.Table
```

Both of these work great independent of each other, but when I try to combine them it fails.

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', DB.Table.DEPT)>0 
THEN
LEFT(DB.Table.DEPT, CHARINDEX(':', DB.Table.DEPT)-1) 
ELSE 
DB.Table.DEPT
END
FROM
(SELECT
REPLACE(
REPLACE(
REPLACE (DB.Table.DEPT,'[NA1] ','') 
,'[NA2] ', '')
,'[NA3] ', '')
FROM
DB.Table)
```

I could really use some guidance with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is syntactically incorrect, because you need an alias for the subquery and for the expression result:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', DEPT)>0 
             THEN LEFT(DEPT, CHARINDEX(':', DEPT)-1) 
             ELSE DEPT
        END)
FROM (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.DEPT,'[NA1] ',''
                                    ), '[NA2] ', ''
                            ), '[NA3] ', ''
                    ) as DEPT
      FROM DB.Table t
     ) t;
```

EDIT:

To see both the original and new department:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', new_DEPT) > 0 
             THEN LEFT(new_DEPT, CHARINDEX(':', newj_DEPT)-1) 
             ELSE new_DEPT
        END),
        Orig_DEPT
FROM (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.DEPT,'[NA1] ',''
                                    ), '[NA2] ', ''
                            ), '[NA3] ', ''
                    ) as new_DEPT,
             t.DEPT as orig_DEPT
      FROM DB.Table t
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff.  Both your answer and Sergio's work fine.  I do have one additional question related to this if you don't mind.  How would this be constructed if I wanted to query and show 2 columns in my results, one with the unedited name and the edited name?

Answer (score 0):

You should always name your subquerys.

Try this:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':', x.DEPT)>0 
    THEN
        LEFT(x.DEPT, CHARINDEX(':', x.DEPT)-1) 
    ELSE 
        x.DEPT
    END AS DEPT
FROM
(
    SELECT
        REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (DEPT,'[NA1] ','') ,'[NA2] ', ''),'[NA3] ', '') AS DEPT
    FROM
    DB.Table
) x
```

Comment: Thank you @bastos.sergio.  Both your answer and Gordon's work fine but I could only vote on one.  I do have one additional question related to this if you don't mind.  How would this be constructed if I wanted to query and show 2 columns in my results, one with the unedited name and the edited name?